# Почему чаще используют "расстроить" вместо "огорчить"?

Tags: синонимы, глаголы

Почему глаголы "расстроить", "расстраивать", "расстроиться", "расстраиваться" используются в значении "огорчать", "огорчить", "огорчаться", "огорчиться" гораздо чаще, чем эти синонимы? Я один считаю, что глаголы "огорч..." имеют гораздо более правильный и чёткий свой смысл? Хотя бы по той причине, что других значений у них нет, в отличии от "расстр...".

Comment: _raven428: глаголы "расстроить", "расстраивать", "расстроиться", "расстраиваться" используются в значении "огорчать", "огорчить", "огорчаться", "огорчиться" гораздо чаще, чем эти синонимы..._ === А на основании чего Вы так считаете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как мне кажется, это просто разные степени негативного восприятия чего-либо. Слово "огорчить" означает "сделать горьким" или в данном контексте "наполнить душу горечью". Слово "расстроить" более ассоциируется со сбоем душевного "настроя" или настроения. То есть история, конечно, неприятная, но не настолько *горькая*. Более мягкая формулировка "расстроить" используется, как мне кажется, чтобы не усугублять и без того неприятную ситуацию.

Answer (score 0):

Слова (условно) делятся на книжные и разговорные. И даже между синонимами дистанция бывает огромна: одно слово высокопарное, другое — просторечное.

Как верно замечено, одно слово — не столь однозначно, т. е. проще в употреблении. Здесь и ответ на вопрос. Правда, насколько часто оно звучит относительно других, — тоже вопрос. Обижать, поражать (неприятно), брать за живое, пугать, пить кровь, вгонять в гроб и т. д., — также слова популярные. Может быть, не сосредотачиваться только на этой паре?

Answer (score 0):

Семантика у этих глаголов не совсем совпадает. Хотя таким образом обозначается негативное эмоциональное состояние, печаль - это статичное (конечное) состояние, в то время как расстройством называют нарушение душевного спокойствия,  когда человек старается осознать причину неприятного события, найти выход, анализирует свои поступки. Горечь, печаль, скорбь - это возможный, но не единственный  итог подобных размышлений, иногда удается вернуть утраченное равновесие.